# How to access hidden field value from java script code(Client side) in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hidden-field

I have defined hidden field in .aspx page(ui)

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID ="hdnExport" runat="server" />
```

Set the value in the following code (java script)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_FinalConfirmOK").on("click", function (event) {
                alert("clicked");
                //document.getElementById("hdnExport").value = "yes";
                $('#hdnExport').val("yes");
               
                alert($('#hdnExport').val());

                document.getElementById('hdnExport').value = "yes";
                //alert("yes");
            });
        });
```

Then accessing hidden field value in aspx.cs code is given below,

```
string exportValue = Convert.ToString(hdnExport.Value);
        string exp = hdnExport.Value.ToString();
        var val = this.hdnExport.Value;
        string latitudeValue = Request.Form[hdnExport.Value];
```

Tried with different ways. but i didn't get value from hidden field. how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

By default, the rendered `id` will differ from the `ID` specified within C# (`hdnExport`). Therefore, (`#hdnExport`) is likely an invalid selector thus no value is set.

Try setting `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the `HiddenField`:

```cs
 <asp:HiddenField ID ="hdnExport" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

This will ensure the hidden field is rendered with `id` as `ID` which would make `#hdnExport` valid.